# Вложенные циклы

Tags: python

Помогите прогнать скрипт определенное количество раз в цикле.

```
users_url = []
i = 1

for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="div1"]'):

    i = i++1
    e = element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "task-avatar")
    users_url.append(e.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a').get_attribute('href'))
    if i > 20:

        break
print(users_url)


for url1 in users_url:
    print(url1)
    time.sleep(2)
    #url1 = driver.current_url ### Забрать ссылку из адресной строки
    result = re.search(r"/([a-z]+)(-?\d+)_(\d+)", url1)
    type_name, owner_id, item_id = result.groups()
    if type_name == "wall":
        type_name = "post"
    url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/likes.add?type=%s&owner_id=%s&item_id=%s&v=5.131&access_token=%s' % (type_name, owner_id, item_id, token)
    req = requests.post(url).text
    print(req)

for item in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '// *[ @ id = "div2"] / div / div[2] / a[1]')[:20]:
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", item)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если этот скрипт является полным(за исключением импортов библиотек), то самым простым решением будет запихать весь этот код в функцию и вызывать в цикле for. Насколько я вижу скрипт юзает глобальный объект от селениума `driver`. Его можно передавать в качестве аргумента функции. Примерно как-то так:

```
def parse(driver):
    ВАШ КОД ЗДЕСЬ
for i in range(10):
    parse(driver)
```